# TeamCity tool wsdl localtion

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I need to trigger TeamCity events with a REST API call. I need the wsdl to get the XML file so I can use those XML files for API calls.

P.S.: I am aware of application.wadl. However, I need wsdl>xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSDL is a file that describes the SOAP API exposed by an application. TeamCity does not expose a SOAP API, and therefore does not provide a WSDL file.

Comment: Thanks Yole!!  However, I need to make the call to teamcity app using rest api calls. Anything relevant would be appreciated!!

Comment: A WSDL file is in any case not required to make REST API calls. The TeamCity REST API is documented here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API

Comment: Got hold of it !! thanks. I suppose, have to find other way to get the xmls!

Comment: You don't need any XMLs to perform REST API calls.